# Robocopy does not copy __init__.py

Tags: python, blender, robocopy

My setup:

1. Windows 10
2. python3
3. Robocopy called via python subprocess.call

My code in python

```
source_path = "."
destination_path = sys.argv[1]

files = {
         4: "__init__.py",
         }

for elem_index in files:
    print("\nelement index [{}]; filename {}\n".format(elem_index, files[elem_index]))
    command = [r"robocopy", source_path, destination_path, files[elem_index]]
    subprocess.call(command)
```

Command-line argument

```
sys.argv[1] = "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\out"
```

I change __init__.py and it is not copied. If file does not have leading and ending underscores **__**, then file is copied.

CMD is run with admin priveleges.

Could someone help me with this case please?

Comment: it works if you call `myscript.py "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\out"` . if you hardcode path inside the script it should be `destination_path = r"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\out"
`

Answer (score 0):

As [@lww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7056842/lww) mentioned, the proposed solution works:

```
destination_path = r"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\out"
```

`r` prefix helps to pass raw string to python script.